# Calculating a price of a bulk order - formula/calculation help requested

Tags: python

I'm new to python and struggling a bit with a practice program I've drummed up.

**Objectives**:

> If quantities of 100 or less, the cost each is $350.
>
> If quantities of 200 or less, the first 100 units cost $350, anything
> less than 200, but more than 100 cost is $300.
>
> If quantities of 200 or more, the first 100 units cost $350, the next
> 100 cost $300, anything above 200 cost is $250.
>
> Calculate the price of the total order.

---

```
quantities = [84, 100, 126, 150, 186, 200, 216, 248]

cost = 0

for i in range(len(quantities)):

    if quantities[i] <= 100:

        cost = (quantities[i] * 350)

        print(f"The cost for an order of {quantities[i]} is ${cost}.")

    elif quantities[i] >= 100 and quantities[i] <= 200:

        cost = cost + (quantities[i] * 300)

        print(f"The cost for an order of {quantities[i]} is ${cost}.")

    elif quantities[i] >= 200:

        cost = cost + (quantities[i] * 250)

        print(f"The cost for an order of {quantities[i]} is ${cost}.")
```

---

Answers I get:

```
The cost for an order of 84 is $29400. 

The cost for an order of 100 is $35000. 

The cost for an order of 126 is $72800. 

The cost for an order of 150 is $117800. 

The cost for an order of 186 is $173600. 

The cost for an order of 200 is $233600. 

The cost for an order of 216 is $287600. 

The cost for an order of 248 is $349600.
```

Answers I should get:

```
The cost for an order of 84 is $29400. 

The cost for an order of 100 is $35000. 

The cost for an order of 126 is $42800. 

The cost for an order of 150 is $50000. 

The cost for an order of 186 is $60800. 

The cost for an order of 200 is $65000. 

The cost for an order of 216 is $69000. 

The cost for an order of 248 is $77000.

Where am I going wrong in my calculation?
```

Answer (score 1):

There are two major issues here.

1. You are using `cost = cost + ...` statements within your blocks but you're using `elif`.  Meaning only **one** of those three blocks will be executed within each iteration of the loop.  You also don't reset `cost` to 0 in each iteration of the loop
2. You're applying the cost to the entire quantity of the order and missing the logic you call out in the requirements to only apply it to a certain range

If I understood your requirements right, the cost of calculation should look something like the following

```py
def calc_cost(quantity):
     if quantity <= 100:
         return 350 * quantity
     elif quantity > 100 and quantity <= 200:
         return 100 * 350 + (quantity - 100) * 300
     else:
         return 100 * 350 + 100 * 300 + (quantity - 200) * 250
```

Then you can do show your calculations with the following

```py
In [5]: for quantity in quantities:
   ...:     print(f'The cost of an order of {quantity} is {calc_cost(quantity)}')
   ...:
The cost of an order of 84 is 29400
The cost of an order of 100 is 35000
The cost of an order of 126 is 42800
The cost of an order of 150 is 50000
The cost of an order of 186 is 60800
The cost of an order of 200 is 65000
The cost of an order of 216 is 69000
The cost of an order of 248 is 77000
```

(Bonus syntax help)
In python you don't have to iterate by using indexes, you can easily do `for quantity in quantities` as shown above

Comment: @Brandon_Davis_OKC And one more syntax tip: `quantity > 100 and quantity <= 200` can be chained together as `100 < quantity <= 200`.